# Gson Serializing HashMap<Teacher, List<Student>>

Tags: android, serialization, deserialization, gson

I have a map where the a key's value is a list of objects. Am able to serialize the keys through `builder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization();` but the values are not serialized as expected because they return a string on deserialization instead of object.

Below is the output of serialization

> [{"id":31001,"name":Teacher"]}, //This is the key
>
> [{"id":33033,"name":"student1"}, {"id":34001,"name":"student2"}]], //This is the list of values

I used the relevant TypeToken which is `TypeToken<HashMap<Teacher, List<Student>>>` but still the list values is returned a string on deserialization instead of object.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

JSON is made up of name/value pairs (where the value side can be a list of things). The name part of that is a string (See: http://json.org)

What you're trying to do is use an object as a name; you can't do that directly. A JSON object can't be a name for a name/value pair.

If you read the [documentation for enableComplexMapKeySerialization](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#enableComplexMapKeySerialization()) it explains what the resulting JSON is going to be.

The JSON it produces (a Map as a JSON array) will deserialize perfectly back to your map. The following is a complete, working example (Java 7).

Note that once I deserialize from JSON back to Java, I'm iterating over the map to get the keys. This is because without `equals()` and `hashCode()` being overridden in `Teacher` there's no way to create a new instance of `Teacher` and have it work as a key (only the reference values are compared).

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        HashMap<Teacher, List<Student>> map = new HashMap<>();
        Teacher t = new Teacher("12345", "Teacher");
        Teacher t2 = new Teacher("23456", "Teacher2");
        ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            list.add(new Student(String.valueOf(i), "Student" + String.valueOf(i)));
        }
        
        map.put(t, list);
        map.put(t2, list);
        
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        
        Gson gson =
            builder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<Teacher,List<Student>>>(){}.getType();
        String json = gson.toJson(map, type);
        System.out.println(json);
        
        System.out.println("\nAfter deserialization:");
        HashMap<Teacher, List<Student>> map2 = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        
        for (Teacher t3 : map2.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(t3.name);
            for (Student s2 : map2.get(t3)) {
                System.out.println("\t" + s2.name);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Teacher {
    public String id;
    public String name;
    
    public Teacher(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Student {
    public String id;
    public String name;
    
    public Student(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": "12345",
      "name": "Teacher"
    },
    [
      {
        "id": "0",
        "name": "Student0"
      },
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Student1"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Student2"
      }
    ]
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": "23456",
      "name": "Teacher2"
    },
    [
      {
        "id": "0",
        "name": "Student0"
      },
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Student1"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Student2"
      }
    ]
  ]
]

After deserialization:
Teacher2
    Student0
    Student1
    Student2
Teacher
    Student0
    Student1
    Student2
```

If you implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` in your `Teacher` class, you would then be able to use a new instance of `Teacher` to retrieve things from the map:

```
class Teacher {

    public String id;
    public String name;
    
    public Teacher(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 37 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
        hash = 37 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        {
            return false;
        }
        final Teacher other = (Teacher) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
}
```

Once you have that, you could do:

```
...
HashMap<Teacher, List<Student>> map2 = gson.fromJson(json, type);
Teacher t = new Teacher("23456", "Teacher2");
List<Student> list = map2.get(t);
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this solution too, but beware of ClassNotFoundException on enableComplexMapKeySerialization on certain HTC devices/versions (HTC decided to include gson themselves, and it's an old version, also overriding the version included in your app).

Comment: Lovely explanation !! I was not aware of **enableComplexMapKeySerialization**