# Gson: Change the way Map-Keys are being serialized

Tags: java, serialization, gson

Ok so I have a `Map<Vector3i,String>` that I want to save, problem is, that I only need the x,z values, so the result should look something like this:

```
{
  "1,2": "test"
  "13,5": "test"
  "9,4": "test"
}
```

That's my `JsonSerializer<Vector3i>`:

```
public class Vector3iAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Vector3i> {
     @Override
     public JsonElement serialize(Vector3i src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(src.getX()+","+ src.getZ());
     }
}
```

But that's what the output looks like:

```
{
  "(1, 0, 2)": "test"
  "(13, 0, 5)": "test"
  "(9, 0, 4)": "test"
}
```

Since serializing a `Vector3i` that doesn't function as key in a `Map` works as intended, I'm asking, why it's behaving differently and how I would fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think calling `enableComplexMapKeySerialization()` on your `Gson.Builder` should do the trick. From [the Gson documentation:](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#enableComplexMapKeySerialization())

> Enabling this feature will only change the serialized form if the map key is a complex type (i.e. non-primitive) in its serialized JSON form. The default implementation of map serialization uses toString() on the key; however, when this is called then one of the following cases apply...

Also, if you are planning to also deserialize the JSON later, you should read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14677564/763935

Comment: Thank you :) I'm already also deserializing the Vector but I didn't include it in the example. Also: Does `enableComplexMapKeySerialization()` decrease performance in some way? If it does I would only use it if it's needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea about the performance impact. I guess there would be *some* impact - but I think you'd have to measure that impact to make an informed decision...